# Why Geometry.Bounds isn't changing properly?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm working with UWP and have this problem. I try to manipulate LineGeometry. When I change StartPoint or EndPoint by TranslateTransform.TransformPoint() my line is cutted by some rectangle. I think it's Bounds part, but is it possible to change it or do something to repair it?

Part to draw Violet Points

```
Path ellipsePoint = new Path();
ellipsePoint.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BlueViolet);
ellipsePoint.StrokeThickness = 3;
ellipsePoint.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkViolet);
var geometry = new EllipseGeometry();
geometry.Center = point;
geometry.Transform = CompositeTransform;
geometry.RadiusX = geometry.RadiusY = 15;
ellipsePoint.Tag = isStartPoint;
ellipsePoint.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
var dragTranslation = new TranslateTransform();
ellipsePoint.RenderTransform = dragTranslation;
ellipsePoint.ManipulationDelta +=
     (s, e) =>
     {
         dragTranslation.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
         dragTranslation.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
         var manPoint = s as Path;
         if (manPoint != null)
             if ((bool)manPoint.Tag)
                 Line.StartPoint = dragTranslation.TransformPoint(point);
             else
                 Line.EndPoint = dragTranslation.TransformPoint(point);
      };
ellipsePoint.Data = geometry;`
```

Line is prepared like below

```
Line = new LineGeometry();
Line.StartPoint = _Points.First();
Line.EndPoint = _Points.Last();
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask